# ion-select no muestra texto completo Ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

Los ion-select de mi formulario no muestran el texto completo, a pesar de tener espacio suficiente. ¿Cómo podría controlar eso?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col col-9>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-select formControlName="articulo1">
          <ion-option *ngFor="let producto of productos" [value]="producto.prod">{{producto.prod}}</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-3>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input formControlName="palets1" type="number" [value]=palets1></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Comment: ¿Alguna idea de cómo podría resolver esto?

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola! Quizá un poco tarde, pero tenía exactamente el mismo problema que tú y lo resolví poniendo esta clase de css en el ion-select:

```
.myCustomSelect{
    max-width: 100% !important;
   }
```

Fuente: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/5427